# Bytes written to a BufWriter aren't actually written

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a small Rust program that echoes lines on /dev/ttyS0 back to the sender:

```
fn echo_loop(device: &str) {
    let f = File::open(device).unwrap();
    let read = BufReader::new(&f);
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(&f);

    read.lines().for_each(|l: Result<String, Error>| match l {
        Ok(line) => {
            let _ = writer.write(line.as_bytes()).unwrap();
            let _ = writer.flush();
            println!("We should have written: {}", line);
        },
        Err(err) => println!("Err!: {:?}", err)
    });
}
```

To test this code, I call the function with `"/dev/tty"` as its argument.

I would expect to be able to type lines on the console that get echoed after I press <kbd>return</kbd>, but I don't get an echo (beside from what I print with the `println!(…)` macro.

The part that reads the lines seems to work, else I couldn't `println!` what I type, but why don't I get the echo by writing to the `writer`?

This is the output of my code (note: The lines “Hello world!” and “That's what I get :-(” is the text I typed, not an output by the program):

```
Hello world!
We should have written: Hello world!
That's what I get :-(
We should have written: That's what I get :-(
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the docs state, `File::open` opens the file in read only mode.

When you try to write, you are writing to the `BufWriter`, which always succeeds. Once you `flush`, you are ignoring the `Result`, which means that even if the writing fails (which it does, since it's read-only), you are ignoring that error.

[`OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html) allows you to open a file both in read and write mode at the same time. Note that reading and writing at the same time can have weird consequences, like reading failing to produce anything after the first write, because the write *replaces* the entire file instead of inserting/appending your writes

Comment: Thanks … indeed that was my error. I was looking completely at the wrong spot. I didn't think of unwrapping the result of flushing, I thought to get an error already on unwrapping the write result. Thanks again …

Comment: How about dropping the `let _ = ...` so the compiler actually tells you where you possibly screwed up?

Comment: You might have gotten an error during writing if you had written more bytes than your buffer can hold. Other than that, using `let _ = foo;` is rarely a good idea, just use `foo;` It also drops the value, but warns you about `#[must_use]` types like `Result`

Comment: @oli_obk-ker I added the “let _ =” because I wasn't sure whether the writing / unwrap is evaluated lazily or not. Normally I don't write it. Here in the code I wanted to make sure that the expression gets evaluated.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer If you use `let _` you are actually making lazy eval worse. If you have a lazy iterator and you never eval it, Rust will tell you. If you place it into `let _`, well, it stays lazy and does nothing. `let _` exists for the rare case where you actually want to ignore failures

Comment: I don't think `let _ = ` will ever force evaluation of anything lazy, or that it is even possible to write a type that behaves this way. (Except with `unsafe`, perhaps.)

Comment: @SebastianRedl This would not be possible even with unsafe (which is itself [limited in what it can do](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/what-unsafe-does.html)) because object move cannot be customized, by design. The only way to implement a type that magically performs an operation when used with `let _ = ...` would be by modifying the compiler.

Comment: @oli_obk-ker Okay, thanks for the explanation/clarification.

Comment: @user4815162342 I was thinking capturing the address of the object when it is first constructed in a raw pointer, implement Drop, and then do something special in drop if the current address is different from the originally captured one. Of course that is incredibly unreliable, but the point here is being evil.